# JAVA_HOME not set while installing logstash

Tags: java, windows, logstash, jruby, logstash-configuration

I am trying to set up Logstash on my windows laptop.

I have a running version of jdk 17.0.2
JAVA_HOME,LS_JAVA_HOME are set up
Java path till bin directory has also been added to PATH system variable.

But I get JAVA_HOME not set.(If I use JAVA_HOME system variable)
Once I also set up LS_JAVA_HOME, it gave me a jruby error. (jruby is set up and working on cmd)

[image: LS_JAVA_HOME error]

Please help !

Regards,
Aarushi

Comment: It looks like it is looking for `jruby` executable in `D:\softwares\logstash-8.4.3\vendor\jruby`

Comment: Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.
Please learn to copy/paste cmd.exe!

The command is as follows: ```jruby --version```

Comment: Hi, I tried all ways of setting up JAVA_HOME path and ruby paths but I am unable to successfully install Logstash on my Windows machine (x64)

Comment: *but I am unable to successfully install Logstash on my Windows machine* I'm wondering then, why we can see a logstash bin directory in your picture?

Comment: Hi @g00se it doesn't run .

Comment: You might not have set env vars such as `PATH` right. You should not need to change to bin directories to run things